# Fill in some inputs and set default value to other inputs

Tags: java, input, enums, switch-statement, case

I have three input choices of different enum areas that a user can type in different donations for. But let's say a user only want to donate money to one or two of these areas, then I want the default value for the other ones to be set to 0, automatically.

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this with some kind of switch-case-method, but I'm stuck. Here is my code at the moment, does someone know how to fix it?

```
public enum Areas { Schools, Healthcare, Environment }

private String socialnr;
private Areas area;
private float percentage = (float) 0.0; //default value for an area if not chosen

//Method to handle the choices:
public synchronized void areaChoice(Areas which) {

switch (which) {
    case Schools: {
        setPercentage(sc.nextFloat());
        break;
    }
    case Healthcare: {
        setPercentage(sc.nextFloat());
        break;
    }
    case Environment: {
        setPercentage(sc.nextFloat());
        break;
    }
}
}
```

DESIRED CONSOLE RESULT:

*"Type 'Schools' to donate to schools, 'Healthcare' for healthcare and 'Environment' for environment donation..."*

Input: *Schools*

Amount: *10*

*"To continue donation type one of the above commands, or 'quit' to quit..."*

Input: *quit*

[Output]:

Schools: 10.0, Healthcare: 0.0, Environment: 0.0

Comment: We need to see more code here.  It's not clear what your `setPercentage()` method is doing, nor where/how you're storing the information that has been input so far by the user.

Answer (score 0):

In this method, you are using `setPercentage(sc.nextFloat());` in all three cases, so you don't really need a switch statement.
You could use an array to store all three percentage values and iterate it through your enum type, since enum is just a bunch of integers given some names (you would iterate through the `Area.values()` array). 
You could also make a method that prints all three values, but only nonzero if the area is the one given (for that,  you could use a switch statement). This option would not require an array and is hence maybe more suitable for your idea. 
Hope that helped! 
P.S. You needn't initialize floats to 0, it is automatically done in Java.